# What is this shrub/tree with small green drupes in southern Texas?

Tags: identification, trees

I'm hoping someone can help me identify this shrub/tree.  We recently purchased this property and are still trying to figure some plants out.  We live in deep south Texas, zone 8/9 but there are many tropical plants on the grounds so it may not be native.
[image]

They are thick glossy topside and fuzzy underside.  The drupes grow individually from the branch on short stems.

Comment: Looks vaguely olive treeish: https://www.google.com/search?q=olive+tree+texas&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=H68SVfSzLsu2yAS__4BQ&ved=0CCsQsAQ&biw=1056&bih=538

Comment: Thank you.  I thought so as well; however, the leaves are substantially larger and the upside is glossy.  I have not been able to find  one that would be a match.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Black Gum tree - a very nice tree to have!  Beautiful red fall color.

Comment: Thank you.  We owned property through the fall and winter and we did not notice any color change nor much growth.   I believe Gum trees are eucalyptus trees.  They do grow here very well.   It has more of a sprawling growth habit.  I will try to upload another pic that shows the growth habit.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a Chrysophyllum oliviforme tree.